# "Off by one" phase difference errors in a cyclotron

Tags: electromagnetism

It is quite trivial to show that the frequency of an electric particle's rotation in a magnetic field is $f=\frac{|q|B}{2\pi m}$ and that the radius of rotation is $r=\frac{mv}{qB}$.

Now I've seen that the frequency of a cyclotron must be equal to $f$. However I'm curious as to whether this is in fact an approximation and if in truth a more careful analysis is necessary.

I'm worried as follows:

1. When an electric particle is in the B-field region no E-field acts upon it. Therefore $dr/dt=0$. Furthermore, the time in the B-field region is half the period $$t_\text{B-field} = \frac{T}{2} = \frac{\pi}{\omega}=\frac{\pi m}{|q|B}$$
2. Let $F_E$ be the electrical force due to the E-Field. Then $a=\frac{F_E}{m_e}$ and $$t_\text{E-Field Region} = -\frac{1}{2}v_0+\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{a^2+8a\Delta x}$$
   where $v_0(r) = \frac{qBr}{m_e}$

Because it takes time for the particle to move through the E-Field, if the E-Field oscillates at the same frequency as the particle's rotation in the B-Field then the E-Field starts to become off phase. Additionally, if the E-Field literally oscillates with frequency $f$ then it is not constant and the particle experiences a nonconstant acceleration.

Something tells me that in reality the E-Field must be switched on and off discretely as follows, assuming the particle starts at one end of it:

1. Turn E-Field on for time $t_E(v_0=0)$.
2. Wait $t_B$
3. Flip direction of E-Field and turn it on for $t_E(v_0=v_1)$
4. ...

I don't quite understand how to formalize my intuition that the phase difference grows. Perhaps there is a way to treat this with phasors?

I'm hoping someone can help clarify this intuition into something more mathematical.

Comment: Could you please draw a diagram to show me your intuition? I find this interesting but I'm unable to see your intuition clearly. I'm sure if I have a diagram I'll be able to formalize your intuition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in your intuition that there should be a phase difference. The cyclotron should ideally have a square shaped electric field such that the reversing of the electric field occurs at the time when the charged particle is in the magnetic field region. That's the ideal theory. Switch on and while the particle is in the magnetic field flip the direction.

But reality is far from ideal. Since, attaining a true square wave is not possible, sinusoidally varying electric field is used in the space between the 'dees'. Although we generally assume that the magnetic field is static, the magnetic field is actually altered in ways to optimize the whole thing.